# docker: command not found with Jenkins build and publish plugin on Mac

Tags: macos, jenkins, docker

I am new to using Jenkins and docker plugins. I have jenkins installed on my Mac Os. I am trying to build a project on jenkins using docker build and publish plugin as a build step.

It fails with below error

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "***"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

Looks like docker is not available to jenkins user but available to root and other user on my Mac.

```
sudo su jenkins
bash-3.2$ docker ps
bash: docker: command not found

sudo su XXX
bash-3.2$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
bash-3.2$
```

Is this some permissions issue? Can you please help?

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed Docker Toolbox https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox ?

Comment: Hi @KeepCalmAndCarryOn..I have docker installed..My other user can run docker commands.`sudo su 'xxx'   bash-3.2$` `docker ps` 
`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
bash-3.2$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the permissions of the docker binary:

```
stat $(where docker)
```

Check the owner and group, 
in osx stuff is usually in [staff](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130685/understanding-the-staff-user-group) group, try adding your `jenkins` user to that group:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a jenkins -t user staff
```

Comment: I also have this issue before, make sure you restart your docker service, and jenkins once you follow the steps.

Comment: @Rogério Peixoto  I couldn't get it working.    stat $(where docker)
-bash: where: command not found
926983176 653 crw--w---- 1 buildserver tty 268435458 0 "Oct 12 17:32:46 2016" "Oct 12 17:32:46 2016" "Oct 12 17:32:46 2016" "Oct 12 17:32:46 2016" 131072 0 0 (stdin)    . I have mac mini version 10.10.5